# How do I set up redirects from an old page URL to a new page URL in Google Sites?

Tags: google-classic-sites

I'm working on updating a bunch of Google Sites-hosted knowledge base entries.

Aside from content and formatting updates, I want to fix some of the URLs since many of them are absurdly long sentences rather than easy to read keywords.  For instance:

> sites.google.com/mysite/iamaskinghowtoredirectagooglesitespageafterrenamingit

instead of

> sites.google.com/mysite/google-sites-redirect-renamed-url

It is very easy to change a page's URL in Google Sites, however, the old URL does not get redirected to the new.  This seems like it'd be an easy thing for Google to accomplish, and yet...

Is there a way that I can make this happen on my end, or am I (and my users, and our search result positions) stuck with silly, unreadable URLs for eternity?

<sub>Edited to add that the reason the URLs were given this absurd format is due to an, I believe, ill-conceived understanding about SEO.</sub>

Comment: As a work around you can use https://bitly.com/ to shorten your URL..Hope you like it..

Answer (score 2):

You can place a **URL Redirector gadget** on the page and configure it to redirect to the other page.

Edit the page, click Insert. Scroll down to More…

Type `URL Redirector` in the search box to find it.

Insert it in your page and configure it.

Comment: It's worth noting that this tool only seems to be available in the older version of Google Sites. After spending 30mins or so trying to find an equivalent for the new Google Sites, I've concluded there isn't anything that works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the old URL, `sites.google.com/mysite/iamaskinghowtoredirectagooglesitespageafterrenamingit`, you can use either JavaScript redirect:

```
<script language=javascript>
function redirect(){
  window.location = "http://example.com";
}
</script>

<body onload="redirect()">

</body>
```

Or simply HTML redirect, like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; http://yourpage">
```

And if the two URLs show you the same content, I do prefer to add some JS to check the URL if its new or old. In case of old URL → redirect to the new one.